# How to fix all critical issues of a server resulted in Nessus vulnerability scan with one click?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nessus

I have 500 servers (AWS ec2 instances), in all the servers Nessus agent installed so I want a short cut to fix all the servers critical issues resulted in Nessus scan with one click. How to achieve that? Any feasibility is available from AWS or Nessus side.

If Any API's or any stuff available for this automation, please do help by telling that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: On a test machine, you can write code (shell, java, w/e you have) to fix each critical finding. Use a sandbox or a test machine, so you can easily rebuild it without affecting anything else, just in case you break something.
Once your program is working, you'll need to run in on every machine.